# How to get dimensions of window when using @react-navigation/native-stack and presentation: 'modal'?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I am trying to use @react-navigation/native-stack and presentation: 'modal' to get more native feel on tablets. My problem is I did not find any way how to get dimensions of modal window. I tried both `useWindowDimensions()` and `Dimensions.get('window/screen')` but I always get size of whole app window, not just the modal window size.

Is there any way how to do that?

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u cant find something u can always use "onLayout", juts put t on wrapper View in modal

```
<View style={{flex:1}} onLayout={(event: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
  // event.nativeEvent.layout.width
  // event.nativeEvent.layout.height
}}>
</View>
```

Comment: Looks like this is currently the only option. Thanks